# nasm segfault in simple programm

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

This code is supposed to output length of key in 1 digit but it outputs segfault.

I can't understand what I've done wrong, the problem must be in the first part of listing, because I took the `flen` function straight from from book:

```
    section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:

    mov edi,key
        call flen
        mov ebx,1
        add ecx,38
        mov edx,1
        int 0x80

    flen:           ;length of string on es:edi
    xor eax,eax
    xor ecx,ecx
    dec ecx
    cld
    repne scasb
    neg ecx
    ret


    xor eax,eax
    inc eax
    int 0x80



section .data
key db '123456',0x0
keylen equ $ - key     ;length of our dear string
plaintext times 256 db 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the exit code to before `flen`. As it is your control flow falls through into `flen` again after the system call returns. Also you should put a system call number into `eax`. Furhermore, the value to be printed must be in memory, and a pointer must be passed. The ascii code of `0` is `48` not `38`, or you could just use `'0'`. Something like this:

```
    section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:

    mov edi,key
        call flen
        add ecx, '0' ; convert to ascii
        push ecx     ; put text onto stack
        mov ecx, esp ; put address into ecx
        mov eax, 4   ; sys_write
        mov ebx,1
        mov edx,1
        int 0x80

    xor eax,eax
    inc eax
    int 0x80

    flen:           ;length of string on es:edi
    xor eax,eax
    xor ecx,ecx
    dec ecx
    cld
    repne scasb
    neg ecx
    ret

section .data
key db '123456',0x0
keylen equ $ - key     ;length of our dear string
plaintext times 256 db 1
```

Note that flen returns `8`.
PS: Learn to use a debugger.